# Obtener columnas concretas en MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos tablas que uno y luego ordeno por `puntos`, obteniendo algo así

```
nombre  | puntos
________________
nombre0 | 9999
nombre1 | 9999
nombre2 | 9999
nombre3 | 9999
yo      | 5000
nombre4 | 2000
nombre5 | 2000
nombre6 | 2000
nombre7 | 2000
nombre8 | 2000
nombre9 | 2000
nombre10 | 2000
```

Lo que necesito es obtener 3 posiciones arriba y tres abajo de mi posición (incluyendo la mía)

*siempre y cuando sea posible, si no hay 3 arriba o abajo, pues las posibles, así

```
nombre  | puntos
________________
nombre1 | 9999
nombre2 | 9999
nombre3 | 9999
yo      | 5000
nombre4 | 2000
nombre5 | 2000
nombre6 | 2000
```

Aquí lo que he podido hacer de momento, que es unir ambas tablas y ordenarla por puntos

```
(SELECT nombre, puntos
   FROM usuarios)
UNION ALL
(SELECT nombre, puntos
   FROM usuarios2)
ORDER BY puntosTotal DESC
```

¿Alguna idea?
¡Gracias!

Comment: Qué contiene cada una de las tablas? No es evidente

Comment: @Alfabravo contienen las columnas id, nombre y puntos, nada más

Comment: En tu resultado esperado ¿Por qué no aparece `nombre0` que tiene el mismo puntaje que `nombre1`?, o sea ¿Por qué 1, 2 y 3 y no 0, 1 y 2?

Comment: @Sal porque una vez ordenados por puntos busco los 3 que estén encima de mi posición y los 3 que estén por debajo de mi posición, nombre0 seria 4 posiciones por encima de mi, entonces no me interesa.

Comment: Pero nombre0 tiene los mismos puntos que nombre3. ¿Por qué nombre0 no es el primero por encima de ti? siendo que tiene el mismo puntaje que nombre3.

Comment: @Sal al ordenarlos por puntos también se ordenan alfabéticamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con MySQL versión 8 o superior, te sirve la función de ventana `row_number()`:

```
WITH t as (
  SELECT u.*
       , row_number() over( order by puntos desc, nombre ) pos
    FROM ( SELECT *
             FROM tabla1 
           UNION
           SELECT * 
             FROM tabla2 
         ) u
)
SELECT t.*
  FROM t
    JOIN ( SELECT pos 
             FROM t
             WHERE nombre = 'yo'
         ) ref
  WHERE abs( cast(ref.pos as signed)
           - cast(t.pos as signed)
           ) <= 3
  ORDER BY t.pos
```

Las n posiciones arriba o abajo a partir de cierta referencia las obtienes con la posición absoluta `abs()` desde la referencia `pos`.

Para versiones anteriores, puedes usar variables de usuario y sub-consultas en lugar de funciones de ventana:

```
SELECT nombre
     , puntos
  FROM ( SELECT t.*
              , @pos:=@pos+1 pos
              , if( nombre = 'yo', @ref:=@pos, null )
           FROM ( SELECT *
                    FROM tabla1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT *
                    FROM tabla2
                   ORDER BY puntos desc, nombre
                ) t
              JOIN ( SELECT @pos:=0, @ref:=null ) v
        ) t2
  WHERE pos between @ref-3 and @ref+3
```

Comment: Uso 10.7.3-MariaDB y me dice que WITH no es conocido :(

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando, el UNION ALL, podrías crear primero la vista que llamaremos v_usuarios, después puedes utilizarla como una tabla.

```
CREATE VIEW v_usuarios AS 
(SELECT nombre, puntos
   FROM usuarios)
UNION ALL
(SELECT nombre, puntos
   FROM usuarios2)
```

```
(SELECT 
    nombre,
    puntos
FROM
    v_usuarios
WHERE
    puntos > (SELECT puntos FROM v_usuarios WHERE nombre = 'yo')
ORDER BY puntos, nombre DESC
LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
    nombre,
    puntos
FROM
    v_usuarios
WHERE
  nombre = 'yo')
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
    nombre,
    puntos
FROM
    v_usuarios
WHERE
    puntos < (SELECT puntos FROM v_usuarios WHERE nombre = 'yo')
ORDER BY puntos ASC, nombre ASC
LIMIT 3)
```

Te dejo el ejemplo en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0fe913/3).

Comment: Necesito hacer exactamente eso, pero con el resultado de unir las tablas usuarios y usuarios2 y no solo de la tabla usuarios, como podría implementarlo? Gracias!!

Comment: Con la consulta que tu has indicado, puedes hacer una vista. Una vez la vista puedes aplicar mi respuesta.

Comment: No conozco mucho de MySql, he estado mirando que son vistas en MySql y no es lo que busco, ya que esta query la quiero ejecutar desde php, como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Si creas una vista, podrás llamarla desde Php como si fuera una tabla, aquí tienes la documentación https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html, lo añado también a la respuesta.

Comment: si pero no es lo que busco, ya que por ejemplo el nombre "yo" va a cambiar, mi idea es tenerlo todo en la query porque es una consulta que solo haré de php y no necesito tener una vista para verla

Comment: Y en cual de los dos tablas estaria 'Yo'?, en cualquiera?

Comment: @japv sí, podría estar en cualquiera de las dos

Comment: Puedes crear la vista en el gestor (PhpAdmin, MySql Workbench,..) y llamarla desde Php, desde Php puedes realizar la consulta utilizando la vista.

Comment: y alguna otra opción que no sea crear una vista?

Comment: Si, en la respuesta donde pongo v_usuarios pegar tu el contenido de la vista el select ... union all select